# Open library for generating Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) files?

Tags: geoserver, export, sld, format, library

I'm developing an app that can create/edit shapefiles and visual representation of vector layers and to export them to some of most common geoportals(f.ex. GeoServer).

I have dealt with .shp, so now i need to deal with styles' code.

I already looked into C++ libs for XML creation, but I think there might be a specific lib for just exactly SHP+SLD exportation.

Is there a library (preferably C++) for SLD export of vector layer styles?

Answer (score 2):

Another option can be using User-friendly Desktop Internet GIS (uDig) which is JAVA based. I tested this **software** to create sld for geoserver.

Source can be reached at [here](https://github.com/locationtech/udig-platform).

Answer (score 2):

Use QGIS and save your layer style as *.sld file. 
After this, load your *.sld file to the GeoServer and connect your .shp to the right style. you can also use multiply styles for one .shp.

Comment: For most styling options, the transfer from QGIS SLD to the Geoserver implementation works fine. However, you might need to tweak your SLD files if you have more complex symbology. Good to know with QGIS: the SLD export transforms your style into a rule-based version of whatever  option you might have chosen (graduated, single symbol. etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a project on Github (http://github.com/ianturton/ShapefileViewer)  that does SLD generation from shapefile. It's in Java and based on GeoTools if that's any help.